# What is the need of SSL/TLS database connection

Tags: database, security, ssl, connection

For most of the use-cases, web server's & databases are hosted within company's network. So the connections between them are always secured. Then why do we need SSL for database connections?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14334/when-is-it-appropriate-to-ssl-encrypt-database-connections

Comment: *"So the connections between them are always secured."* - What makes you think so?

Comment: Putting an analogy here.... we need lock for our house only at exit points (for example main door or back door..) We do not need locks from my leaving to bed room for example

Comment: Interesting analogy. But in companies there are commonly also locks on various office doors. And only few employees have the keys for the locker server room etc. It is not that everybody is trusted to have access to everything in a company and this extends to the network too.

Comment: Good example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the philosophy of zero trust networking. It seems to be norm that people don't care extra resource/power usage by SSL. The same thing is happening with https everywhere movement.
It also makes the migration to cloud environment a little bit easier, where you can't trust the network.